# Access VBA Set Textbox Equal To Query Result

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am running this syntax to query a table and set a texbox equal to the `rs` problem is the textbox is not actually setting to a value.  It remains null.  What should be altered in this so the textbox value is set to the value or `rs`

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDb

strSQL = "Select MAX(pkid)+1 from tblInfo"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

Do While Not rs.EOF

    txtID = rs

Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are trying to set a recordset to a textbox object.  You need to set the Text/Value of the textbox and you need to access the fields of the recordset.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDb

strSQL = "Select MAX(pkid)+1 from tblInfo"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

Do While Not rs.EOF
    txtID.SetFocus 'set the focus so we can add the text
    txtID.Text = rs.Fields(0).Value
    'txtID.Value = rs.Fields(0).Value 'uncomment out if you don't need focus on the textbox and comment out the previous 2 lines
Loop
```

Comment: Use `txtID.Value = ...` then you won't need `.SetFocus`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do all this in a single line:

```
Me!txtID.Value = DMax("pkid", "tblInfo") + 1
```